# Delete a row with ajax in mvc3

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to do a delete with Ajax from a list view and when I press button "Delete (Ajax)" it doesn't enter on the controller method, it generates the error:

> The resource cannot be found. Description: HTTP 404. The resource you
>   are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed,
>   had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review
>   the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>   Requested URL: /Idea/DeleteAjax/30

Any ideas?

```
 //controller 

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult DeleteAjax(int id)
        {
            IdeeRepository ideeRepo = new IdeeRepository();

            WIKIIDEE idee = new WIKIIDEE();
            idee = ideeRepo.GetIdeeByID(id);

            ViewModels.AjaxResponseVM ajaxVM;

            try
            {
                ideeRepo.DeleteIdea(idee);
                ideeRepo.SaveIdea();

                ajaxVM = new ViewModels.AjaxResponseVM(Convert.ToInt32(idee.ID), "Idee eliminato con successo!");
            }
            catch
            {
                ajaxVM = new ViewModels.AjaxResponseVM(-1, "Error!");
            }

            return Json(ajaxVM);
        }
```

// view

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Elimina Idea(Ajax)", "DeleteAjax", "Idea", new { id = ViewBag.Ideas[i].ID }, new AjaxOptions { Confirm = "Are you sure!", OnSuccess = "DeleteResponse", HttpMethod = "POST" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are referencing the following files:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```